# Can't update or remove PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: apt, ppa, postgresql

The last update of PostgreSQL 9.1.7 seems to break my APT.

When I try to update, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.1 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib-9.1 : Depends: postgresql-9.1 (= 9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to run `apt-get -f install`, same error.

Finally, I tried to remove everything using `apt-get --purge remove postgresql`, same error again.

Note: I installed PostgreSQL using the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone to help me?

Comment: Try `aptitude`. You probably have to install it first. When you run it, there should be a category of packages with unmet dependencies and you should be able to work them out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the FAQs. They have a lot of good answers to these kinds of questions.

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)